# Combine different UIView classes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, multiple-inheritance

For example, I have subclasses of a UIView like RoundedView, ShadowedView, GradientView and one may want to combine these into the one greatest class. But since we don't have multiple inheritance in a C++ sense and don't want a hierarchy of these classes, what is the best approach to do this? I'm considering the protocol extension, but since I'm novice in Swift I can spoil the design.

UPD. Thanks @Robert Dresler for his very descriptive answer. That's what I come up with. But are there any enhancements to concrete class implementation, because there always will be presence of a boilerplate code.

```
protocol Gradientable where Self: UIView {
    var startColor: UIColor { get set }
    var endColor: UIColor { get set }
    func updateColors()
}

extension Gradientable {

    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

    func updateColors() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
    }
}

protocol CornersRoundable where Self: UIView {
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { get set }
    func roundCorners()
}

extension CornersRoundable {
    func roundCorners() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}

@IBDesignable
class SuperbView : UIView, Gradientable, CornersRoundable {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6.0 {
        didSet { roundCorners() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = .white {
        didSet { updateColors() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet { updateColors() }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        roundCorners()
        updateColors()
    }
}
```

Comment: Protocol extension push you to refactor subclasses to make every subclass spits out their functionality from the inherent hierarchy. So you need to do that first. In your proposed subsubclass, it’s just a container for those functionalities. If design well, you don’t need to write too many code over here.

Comment: If one subclass is a major one, sub subclass can be his subclass to reduce a lot of codes

Answer (score 0):

Considering the protocol extension is very good point. So let's have a look on it.

---

#### Declaring

Let's start with simple protocol declaration

```
protocol Colorable where Self: UIView {
}
```

we're using keyword `protocol` following by name of the protocol. Then when we want to, we can constrain our protocol to specific types, this does that `where Self: Type`. Let's say we constrain it to `UIView`. Now our protocol can be used on type `UIView` (and on all inherited classes).

Now let's declare some variable

```
protocol Colorable where Self: UIView {
    var mainColor: UIColor { get set }
}
```

... we're declaring, that every view which conforms to protocol `Colorable` has to have declared variable `mainColor`.

---

#### Implementation

Now, how to implement our protocol? The convention in Swift is to declare protocol in extension, but you can also declare it right after declaring type

```
extension MyView: Colorable {}
```

or

```
class MyView: UIView, Colorable {}
```

Clear? Now we have to add all required stuff from protocol declaration. Since we declared just one variable let's put it and let's give give it a value

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var mainColor: UIColor = .black
}
```

---

#### Adding functions

Is everything still clear? Okay, let's continue with adding some method to our protocol

```
protocol Colorable where Self: UIView {
    var mainColor: UIColor { get set }
    func doSomethingWithColor()
}
```

now we have to declare this method inside our view subclass or we can declare this method inside extension of protocol. Since we know, that this protocol also requires declaration of variable `mainColor`, we can work with it

```
extension Colorable {
    func doSomethingWithColor() {
        backgroundColor = mainColor
    }
}
```

and then we are able to call this on any view which conforms to this protocol

```
let myView = MyView()
myView.doSomethingWithColor()
```

---

#### Methods with generic constraints

Now last part. Let's say we have `UIViewController` which includes three views of different types and all conforms to protocol `Colorable`. This allows us to use generic constraint on method. This constraint declares type, let's say `T`, which conforms to protocol. And this type we can use as parameter of method and we will be 100% sure, that we're passing view which has exactly what we need, in our case, variable `mainColor`

```
func changeBorderColorOf<T: Colorable>(_ view: T) {
    view.layer.borderColor = view.mainColor.cgColor
}
```

now we can call this method and as parameter we can pass any `UIView` which conforms to our protocol

```
let myView = MyView()
changeBorderColorOf(myView)
```

---

Generics are a large topic so I hope this will help you get started! ;-)

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. Could you please check my update

Comment: @JosephKirtman honestly, I’m not sure what you are asking for in your edit, it’s not very clear. Of course there always be some code which you will has to write, but with good code organization your code will be reusable and easy to maintain.